# JNLP application blocked by java security

Tags: java, security, jnlp

I signed my custom JAR with valid code signing certificate but still geting this kind of error.

```
Your security settings have blocked an application from running due to missing a "Permission" manifest attribute in the main jar.
```

bellow is my sample JNLP

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<!-- JNLP File for CardBuilder Application --> 
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://www.testpath.com/CardBuilder/" > 
   <information> 
      <title>Card Builder</title> 
      <vendor>cardbuilder</vendor> 
      <description>Allows you to design a cards</description> 
      <description kind="short"></description> 
      <icon href="builder_icon.gif" />

      <shortcut online="true">
          <desktop/>
          <menu submenu="testpath.com"/>
      </shortcut> 
      <offline-allowed/> 
      <association mime-type="application-x/crd-file" extensions="crd"/>
     </information> 
    <resources> 
        <j2se version="1.6+" java-vm-args="-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -Dsun.java2d.d3d=false -Xmx512M"/>
        <jar href="MyCards.jar"/> 
        <extension name="jaxen-1.1" href="jaxen-1.1.jnlp"/>
        <extension name="jdom" href="jdom.jnlp"/>
        <extension name="looks-2.1.1" href="looks-2.1.1.jnlp"/>
        <extension name="saxpath" href="saxpath.jnlp"/>                  
        <extension name="forms-1.0.7" href="forms-1.0.7.jnlp"/>
        <extension name="log4j-1.2.8" href="log4j-1.2.8.jnlp"/>
        <jar href="commons-logging.jar"/>
        <jar href="commons-codec-1.3.jar"/>
        <jar href="commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar"/>  
        <jar href="Poker.jar" download="lazy"/>
        <jar href="BridgeStyle.jar" download="lazy"/>
        <jar href="Blank.jar" download="lazy"/>
        <jar href="fonts.jar"/>
        <jar href="Filters.jar"/>
    </resources> 
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <application-desc main-class="com.cards.CardsUI"/> 
</jnlp>
```

Here is my manifest file.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.7.0
Application-Name: Card Builder
Codebase: *
Permission: all-permissions
Created-By: 1.5.0_09-b03 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
```

Comment: Double-check MyCards.jar, and make sure the manifest is present as `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`.

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).

Comment: ..also be sure to check the ***preview*** when posting question.  Most of the JNLP was not appearing.